# Can we determine whether a polynomial of even degrees has at least one real root just from its discriminant?

Tags: polynomials, roots

As we all know that the discriminant of the quadratic polynomial $ax^{2}+bx+c$ with $a\neq0$ is: $\Delta=b^{2}-4ac $, and when $\Delta$ is smaller than zero, we can determine that the quadratic polynomial has no real roots. Can we do it in the same way to the polynomial of degree n($n\geq3$)? If not, is there any other discriminant-like formula that helps to determine?

Comment: First of all, "no real roots" can only occur for even degree, The discriminant gives a necessary but not sufficient condition for this case. But the discriminant is very complicated even for degree $4$, so I suggest the use of the sturm chain to count the real roots.

Comment: What do you mean by "has real roots" : is it "has **all** its roots real" or "has at least one real root" ?

Comment: @JeanMarie In answer to your question, consider $(x^2 + 1)(x-1).$

Comment: @Peter I just want to determine whether the polynomial has real root or not, no need to count the number of real roots. Is it necessary to use sturm chain? Is there any other simpler way?

Comment: @Eric: the Sturm method is the only one that tells you the number of real roots, and there is no simplification if you ask "at least one". Descartes' sign rule may work "by chance".

Comment: @YvesDaoust Oh, I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The discriminant is defined for polynomials of all degrees. Suppose a real polynomial $p(x)$ has complex roots $r_i$, then $\Delta = \prod_{i < j} (r_i - r_j)^2$. This works for polynomials of degree 2: If its roots are real, $\Delta$ is a square of real numbers, which is non-negative; If not, $\Delta$ is a square of purely imaginary numbers.

Unfortunately, the discriminant doesn't distinguish, for quartic polynomials, whether there are four distinct real roots, or four complex roots: both cases give a positive discriminant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But it there any "discriminant"-like formula that helps to determine if the even-degree polynomial has real root or not?

Comment: @Eric I guess there is no simple one, and I'm thinking about a proof

Comment: @Eric Suppose there is a polynomial in the coefficients that changes sign according to whether the quartic has roots, then it must has the factor $\Delta$, which also changes signs when the quartic has 4 roots. No polynomial factor will save you.

Comment: I'm not very sure, but I think any analytic function that is defined on the whole space of coefficients won't do...

Answer (score 2):

Hereafter "complex" will mean "non real".

In complement of the excellent answer of @Trebor, here are some numerical examples of 4th degree polynomials equations:

$$ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e=0$$

with their resp. number of complex roots $n$ and their discriminant $\Delta$ (expression given below). Indeed, the sign of $\Delta$ doesn't "discriminate" cases $n=4$ and $n=0$ (in both cases $\Delta > 0$).

Please note that, though these coefficients $b,c,d,e$ have been randomly generated (with $a=1$, WLOG):

- the cases where $n=2$ are dominant.
- there are 5 cases where $n=0$ (4 complex roots) vs. only one case where $n=4$ (4 real roots); this reflects a more general probabilistic result saying that a random polynomial of degree $n$ has a number of *real* roots  asymptoticaly, (i.e., when  $n \to \infty$) equal to $\frac{2}{\pi} \ln(n)$ ; see [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1943-49-04/S0002-9904-1943-07912-8/home.html), [here](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Elnicolae/Kac_Rice.pdf) and [here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/328813079.pdf).

$$\begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|r|c|r|}
\hline
a&b&c&d&e&n&\Delta \ \ \ \ \ \ \\
\hline
1&3&4&2&0&2&-16\\
1&-4&-4&-5&-2&2&-47691\\
1 & -2 & 2 & -2 & 1 & 2 & 0\\
1&5&-1&3&2&2&-130700\\
1&4&-2&-3&-4&2&-194811\\
1&0&1&1&0&2&-31\\
1&3&5&-4&3&0&107113\\
1&-4&0&2&2&2&-18608\\
1&0&1&-2&1&0&272\\
1&2&3&3&-5&2&-65543\\
1&-4&4&0&-5&2&-25600\\
1&1&2&-5&-3&2&-48188\\
1&2&3&1&4&0&13577\\
1&5&-2&2&1&2&-44491\\
1&-2&2&3&-4&2&-12275\\
1&3&5&5&-1&2&-9843\\
1&-2&0&3&3&0&11421\\
1&-3&-1&2&-3&2&-30263\\
1&3&-3&-2&0&4&2484\\
1&-4&0&-2&1&2&-11056\\
1&1&-1&1&-2&2&-3600\\
1&-1&1&-4&-4&2&-42800\\
1&-4&-4&-3&2&2&-146219\\
1&0&4&1&2&0&2917\\
\hline\end{array}$$

Remark: on the third line, the discriminant is $0$, meaning that there is a double root. Indeed, in this case, we have this factorization:

$$x^4-2x^3+2x^2-2x+1=(x^2+1)(x-1)^2$$

Appendix: The (huge) expression of

$$\Delta=\begin{cases}256a^3e^3-192a^2bde^2-128a^2c^2e^2\\
+144a^2cd^2e-27a^2d^4+144ab^2ce^2\\
-6ab^2d^2e-80abc^2de+18abcd^3+16ac^4e\\
-4ac^3d^2-27b^4e^2+18b^3cde\\
-4b^3d^3-4b^2c^3e+b^2c^2d^2\end{cases}$$

Comment: excellent answer! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: I have added the "Kac-Rice formula" and references.